# ReactJS Promise - _this.setExitAnimation is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I would use promise to set my animation, I have tried to create a promise'chains to release the new value of my animation. 
However console return me:

> _this.setExitAnimation is undefined
>   Here my reactJS snippet:

```
/***** HERE TRIGGER THE setAnimation's PROCESS THEN INJECT 
UPDATED ANIATION IN COMPONENT *****/
textAnimation=()=>{            

    // CALL THE PROMISE'S CHAIN
      this.setState({elementType:"text"}, 
        () => this.routeAnimationPosition
          .then((anim) => { 
            console.log("promise resolved: ", anim)
            // set new animations
        this.setState({firstLineAnimation:anim}, 
          () =>     console.log("after setState textAnimation: ", this.state.textAnimation)
          )
{...}

/***** HERE START THE PROMISE'S CHAIN TO UPDATE ANIMATION'S NAME *****/

routeAnimationPosition= new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{ 
  console.log("in routeAnimationPosition")
  if(this.state.exitLoop){ 
    this.setExitAnimation.then((anim)=> resolve(anim)); 
  }else{ 
    this.setEnterAnimation.then((anim)=> resolve(anim));
  }  
})

setEnterAnimation=new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{ 
  console.log("in setEnterAnimation")
  if(this.state.elementType ==="text"){
    if(this.state.currentView % 2 === 0){ 
      this.setState({textAnimation:enterDownAnimation});
      resolve(enterDownAnimation);
{...}
```

I can't figure out what is wrong, it seems to me my animation process is fair,
any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: You are calling `this.routeAnimationPosition()` but `this.routeAnimationPosition` is a promise and not a function so it can't be called like that.

Comment: Yeah I have just figure it out an instant ago, now it returns me undefined, I'm travelling StackOverflow to find some answers

Comment: Maybe you should first try find the solution by reading the documentation of how promises work and debugging your code and **only then** search for the solution on stack overflow.

Comment: I have just read some docs about it and I have tried some debugging so Thanks to no assume what people do or not, I have discover some clue, so that was a great move and I go forward, docnazi.